# He, need help in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

Who knows how to solve this type of error when variables are interconnected

Example:

```
b = 1
a = b + c
c = a + b
```

Error: line 2: undeclared identifier "c"

It turns out "c" is spelled out in the code, but below. But Pine does not see

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow, I've removed the Russian translation, as this is a English only site. In case you want to post this question in Russian, you can do so at: [Stackoverflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I believe like most programming languages PineScript executes sequentially. At the point line 2 is executed, line 3 has not yet been seen. In this model, this error is completely normal, saying that you are doing something wrong (using `c` before its value is known). There are some other models of execution, for example the constraint-based one, where all the equations need to be satisfied, just like in mathematics; in such a model, your program is a contradiction, because it means `a = 1 + c; c = 1 + c + b; c - c = 1 + b; 0 = 2` which is impossible. What did you want your program to do?